# Replace specific string in url with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Lets say I have a string of:

`http://mitavite.v10.fw8.co/kb/tags/breedings~breeding~foobar~breeding~foo`

Lets call everything after `/tags/` a **TAG**.

Lets then say I want to remove the tag, "breeding".

I want to create a regex that can search the string for the required tag, if it's suffixed by a `~` append that to the result, and remove it from the string. Here's what I have tried:

`breeding([?!.*\~]|[^!?a-zA-Z0-9]+)` while this may work in my test string, if I then change `breeding` to `foo` it doesn't select the last tag in the string.

My problem is it only finds tags that are proceded by a `~`, I think what i need to match on is:

`1. the tag name by it self, not followed by any other character except for the`~` character

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/kR9mG4/1

I cannot figure out how to match this one.

Comment: Please clearly describe your problem.

Comment: You could also just convert it into an array: `var tags = url.split('/tags/')[1].split('~')`, remove the element with `tags.splice(tags.indexOf('breeding'), 1)`, and re-construct the new URL with `... + tags.join('~')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may be looking for something like this:

```
str = str.replace(/\bbreeding\b~?/g, '')
```

A word boundary `\b` does not consume any characters. It asserts that on one side there is a word character, and on the other side there is not. Adding the quantifier `?` will match `~` between zero and one time.

Comment: This worked great! Would you mind explaining this a bit more? Mainly the \b~? section?

Comment: Also, if I have my `~` stored in a variable, how could I include that into this replace without manually inserting it? ie, something like: `var t = '~'; str.replace(/\bbreeding\b'+t+'?/g, '')` ?

Comment: Okay great, one last thing (which i didn't include in my question, is that the 'tags, can have a plus symbol which this regex doesnt match, example: `http://mitavite.v10.fw8.co/kb/tags/breedings~all+posts~tagname`

Comment: I meant any tag, for this instance, lets say I want to remove `all+posts`.

Comment: No, this is dynamic, I'm saying the regex you have given my does NOT work when I pass it a string of 'all+posts' Demo: `http://jsfiddle.net/AnBc6/1/`, I also swapped the position of the `~`

Comment: What if I can't though? what if I already have that value in a variable? how can I escape it if it's a variable not a string?

Comment: @ShannonHochkins use the function I created like so: http://jsfiddle.net/AnBc6/5/

Answer (score 0):

To remove `breeding~`, how about simply:

```
replaced = yourString.replace(/\bbreeding~/g, "");
```

Comment: The OP says suffix of ~